# pinning shortcut widget for lower api

Tags: android, shortcut

Is there any way to use this feature on android devices with api lower than **Nougat**

[image]

Comment: That entirely is implemented at the launcher level, not the OS. Maybe the API to interact with that app is only in latest SDK, but long click is supported by any version

Comment: @cricket_007  you say there is no way? or at least any way to simulate that feature?

Comment: I'm saying if possible (which it obviously is, according to screenshot), then it's very tightly integrated with whatever launcher app the user has installed

Answer (score 3):

[`ShortcutInfo` is only available since API 25](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/pinning-shortcuts-widgets.html), and unless they release a support library for that, then I'm afraid it is not possible.

> If your app targets Android 7.1 (API level 25) or higher, you can define shortcuts to specific actions in your app. These shortcuts can be displayed in a supported launcher.

Keywords on the page are *a **supported** launcher*, so the one on the Google Pixel might work, for example, but don't expect an LG or Samsung device to also allow the same feature

---

The current action for long clicking an icon exists, though. It allows you delete  or move apps on your home pages, but, again, that's up to the launcher to implement and support  that action.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is supported in launcher. Long press on app icon is implemented in API 25 or higher, If the user doesn't allow the shortcut to be pinned to the launcher, your app won't receive a callback.